# Simulate Bad Network with Retrofit 2 (on Actual, i.e. Non-mocked, API)

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

In Retrofit 1.x I used the following pattern to create api service classes that simulated a bad network connection for certain build variants.

```java
// Retrofit 1
private <T> T create(Class<T> apiServiceClass) {
    T apiService = restAdapter.create(apiServiceClass);
    if (!BuildConfig.IS_PRODUCTION_BUILD) {
        endpoints = mockRestAdapter.create(apiServiceClass, apiService);
    }
    return apiService;
}
```

The cool thing about this is that my actual API endpoints are used. This way I can see how the app behaves on a flaky connection and I don't need to provide mocked/artificial responses.

Now, in Retrofit 2 the API for `MockRestAdapter` or rather `MockRetrofit` changed completely. `MockRetrofit#create` now returns a `BehaviorDelegate`. If I try to use the same pattern as before

```java
// Retrofit 2
private <T> T create(Class<T> apiServiceClass) {
    T apiService = retrofit.create(apiServiceClass);
    if (!BuildConfig.IS_PRODUCTION_BUILD) {
        endpoints = mockRetrofit.create(apiServiceClass).returning(???);
    }
    return apiService;
}
```

I get stuck on the `returning(???)`. `returning` expects a `Call<?>` implementation. But I can't seem to figure out how to implement it to make it work like my Retrofit 1 example (maybe it's not intended to).

**So my question is: In general, how can I achieve the above Retrofit 1 pattern for simulating a bad network on an actual API with Retrofit 2?**

Answer (score 16):

Eventually I figured it out. The idea is to use OkHttp's application interceptors. Here's the solution.

First, create a `NetworkBehavior`.

```java
final NetworkBehavior behavior = NetworkBehavior.create();
behavior.setDelay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
behavior.setFailurePercent(50);
behavior.setVariancePercent(50);
```

Of course you can provide `behavior` to a UI component to dynamically change these values.

When configuring the `OkHttpClient` add the following interceptor.

```java
final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
if (!BuildConfig.IS_PRODUCTION_BUILD) {
    builder.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor());
    builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(behavior.calculateDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (behavior.calculateIsFailure()) {
                return new Response.Builder()
                        .code(500)
                        .message("MockError")
                        .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                        .request(chain.request())
                        .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "MockError"))
                        .build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(chain.request());
        }
    });
}
```

Note that you should add a logging interceptor *before* so that request logs are properly shown. The manually created response object can of course be adapted to your liking. Some values are obligatory (e.g. `protocol` or `request`). If you don't specify them you will receive NPEs. The same approach would actually also work for Retrofit 1.

Comment: Exactly what I search. Thanks!

Comment: First off thanks for answering. I too was hoping to solve the problem with `MockRetrofit`. I ended up doing something similar to you. But if you are rolling your own by using `OkHttp` `Interceptor` instead, you might as well write your own `NetworkBehavior` class that does what you need. Otherwise, you're relying on the entire `retrofit-mock` lib just to use two methods on one class.

Comment: dependency in build.gradle is `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.3.0'`  (version 2.3.0 currently)